# Django 1 insert data per day

Tags: python, django

if the user inserted data with the same day his inserted his account the record will updated, and if the user insert data tomorrow or following day it will insert.

I just want that 1 data inserted data per day

this is my views.py

```
insert_1tab, created = TrCustomerEmployeeSupplierSubmittedRecords.objects.get_or_create(
    fmCustomerID=company,
    fmCustomerLocationID = location,
    firstname=firstname,
    lastname=lastname,
    middleInitial=middlename,
    bodyTemperature=temperature,
    fmCustomerSectionID = sections,
    employee_number=employeno,
    contactNumber=cnumber,
    address=tirahan,

)
if not created:  
    insert_1tab.save()
```

this is my models.py

```
class TrCustomerEmployeeSupplierSubmittedRecords(models.Model):
    fmCustomerID = models.ForeignKey('FmCustomer', null=True, blank=True,
                                     verbose_name="Customer")
    fmCustomerLocationID = models.ForeignKey('FmCustomerLocation',null=True, blank=True,
                                             verbose_name="CustomerLocation")
    dateSubmitted = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, null=True, blank=True)
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    middleInitial = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    bodyTemperature = models.FloatField()
    fmCustomerSectionID = models.ForeignKey('FmCustomerSection', null=True, blank=True,
                                            verbose_name="CustomerSection")
    employee_number = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
    contactNumber = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the `datetime.now().date()` to get the current date and update the record.

```
from datetime import datetime
today_date = datetime.now().date()
TrCustomerEmployeeSupplierSubmittedRecords.update_or_create(
    dateSubmitted=today_date,
    employee_number=employeno,
    defaults={
        'fmCustomerID': company,
        'fmCustomerLocationID': location,
        'firstname': firstname,
        'lastname': lastname,
        'middleInitial': middlename,
        'bodyTemperature': temperature,
        'fmCustomerSectionID': sections,
        'employee_number': employeno,
        'contactNumber': cnumber,
        'address': tirahan
    }
)
```

This will search for the records withdateSubmitted todayand employee_number = employeno.
If it doesn't exist for the day, it will create it. Or else just update the existing record.

Comment: hi, you could have a filed to record the date of creation of the object, then it's just a simple python `if` statement to compare today and date_of_creation of the last object of the model! like this: `import datetime` `today = datetime.date.today()` `if today is not ur_model.objects.latest().creation_date:` `so_create_new()` `else:` `update_(ur_model.objects.latest())`

Comment: The model already have such field `dateSubmitted` which will have the created time_stamp because of  `auto_now_add=True`. No need of extra field I guess.

Comment: ok, so I hope the rest of the answer could help you. actually the `latest()` method is the trick